# Could not download Resources

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka

> when i try to create discovery server i am getting this error
>
> > "Could not download sources or javadoc
> >     Could not read maven project
> >     Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
> >     [ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to transfer org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:pom:Hoxton.RC1 from https://repo.spring.io/milestone was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of spring-milestones has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:pom:Hoxton.RC1 from/to spring-milestones (https://repo.spring.io/milestone): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target @ line 47, column 16
> >     [ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server:jar is missing. @ line 27, column 15 Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
> >     [ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to transfer org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:pom:Hoxton.RC1 from https://repo.spring.io/milestone was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of spring-milestones has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:pom:Hoxton.RC1 from/to spring-milestones (https://repo.spring.io/milestone): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target @ line 47, column 16
> >     [ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server:jar is missing. @ line 27, column 15"

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>io.mgk</groupId>
    <artifactId>discovery-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>discovery-server</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.RC1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

Comment: Are you behind any network proxy? Please check if you can build project using maven. It looks to be some network/proxy issue.

Comment: yes it is a proxy issue i found it